# SOLR Index: needs to show field although it is null. Also can we have actual itemid instead of guid in index fields

Tags: solr

We are building some specific indexes for third party and they have specific requirement.

1. Always needs to have all fields, so if field is null then they want field with `empty ("")` value.
   We tried with setting default value to field but it didn't worked
   [image]

   Also we need it for all fields i.e. default + computed
2. They want actual Sitecore item ID instead of `Guid` e.g. _group to be `{F35E4CB3-3EB9-4FC2-9211-EB9F74D35F0B}` instead of `f35e4cb33eb94fc29211eb9f74d35f0b`

Comment: Why require empty fields to exist and use the short id? Are they querying the index directly?

Comment: Yes they are querying it directly so wanted all these fix at our side

Comment: did you try `required="true"`?

Comment: yes tried it but it didn't worked as well

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly store Null or Empty value but you can assign `nullValue` or `EmptyString` value as shown below

```
<fieldType fieldName="gender" returnType="text" nullValue="NULLVALUE" emptyString="EMPTYVALUE"/>
```

Reference Link -
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/queries-for-null-or-empty-strings.html

Regarding GUID, Sitecore will always remove `"{","}","-"` as it usages `ShortID.Encode(guid)` to cleanup before GUID gets indexed but this can be achieved with the help of `Update Request Processors`. Every update request received by Solr is run through a chain of plugins known as Update Request Processors.

You can reference SO link for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60375628/2580562

Comment: thanks for the details, will try it and confirm